# PG-Metric dr/dt

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, velocity

at the moment, I investigate some time in learning General Relativity and there I saw the Painlevé-Gullstrand Metric which is given as

$ds^2 = -dT^2 + \left(dr+\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r}} dT\right)^2 + r^2 d\theta^2 
+ r^2 \sin^2\theta d\phi^2$

and the time coordinate $t$ is replaced by

$T(t, r) = t + 2 \sqrt{rr_s} + r_s \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{r/r_s}-1}{\sqrt{r/r_s} +1}\right|$

Now, I want to compute some properties for a massive particle which falls into a black hole from infinity, where I want to compute the velocity

$\dot{r} = dr/d\tau$.

So I would begin with the fact that the particle firstly rests at infinity and use the conservation of energy and momentum.

But how do I come then with the Killing Vector to the velocity?

Comment: PG coordinates are coordinates that are not adapted to the timelike Killing vector. The coordinates simplest for your purposes would be the Schwarzschild coordinates. Did you try that?

Comment: Hmm, no I want to stay in the PG basis ;)

Comment: @Armani42 It is not clear to me exactly what you want to do? Do you want to find the Killing vectors? Find conserved quantities?